# How can I maintain a variable in a recursive function?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I'm trying to get all the keys in an object, in a recursive way:

```js
let keys = [];

const getAllKeys = (object) => {
  //Supposedly, `keys` should be here.
  Object.keys(object).some((k) => {
    if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === "object") {
      keys.push(k);
      getAllKeys(object[k]);
    }
  });
  return keys;
};

const obj = {
  key1: {
    key2: {
      key3: {}
    }
  }
};

getAllKeys(obj);

console.log(keys);
```

And as you can see, it works, but the problem is that `keys` is outside this function, but I need it to be inside so that I can just `import` this function and use it. I tried wrapping it in another, inner function, but it doesn't work.

What can I do here?

Comment: I ran the snippet and it is working fine. What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy I mean, sorry to say but the question is clear as to what my issue is. The code is not working.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari The question is about how to retrieve deeply-nested object keys.

Comment: Your snippet outputs key1, key2, key3, which in my understanding are all the keys in the nested object. What other output did you expect?

Comment: @DanielJames `but I need it to be inside`. Where is this inside you are talking about ?

Comment: If you have a problem, then post the code that has the problem, not the code that works. This is utterly confusing.

Comment: @trincot But the code was posted, I have a working version of it **but my problem is that `keys` is outside the  main function.** I can't use this function as an import.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a wrapper function to hold the accumulator:

```js
const getAllKeys = (object) => {
    let keys = [];

    let getAllKeysInner = (o) => {
        Object.keys(o).forEach((k) => {
            keys.push(k);
            if (o[k] && typeof o[k] === "object") {
                getAllKeysInner(o[k]);
            }
        });
    }

    getAllKeysInner(object)
    return keys;
};

//

const obj = {
    key1: {
        key2: {
            key3: {}
        }
    }
};

console.log(getAllKeys(obj))
```

Note that your code needed a few fixes.

FWIW, this particular problem can be done simpler, without any accumulator at all:

```
const getAllKeys = (o) =>
    (o && typeof o === "object")
        ? Object.keys(o).flatMap(k => [k, ...getAllKeys(o[k])])
        : []
```

although the accumulator version might be more efficient since it doesn't allocate 1000s temporary arrays.

Finally, the VLAZ's idea to carry the accumulator around is a sane one, because is it as efficient as the wrapper version. It can be written concisely like this:

```
const getAllKeys = (o, keys=[]) =>
    o
    && typeof o === "object"
    && Object.keys(o).forEach(k => keys.push(k) && getAllKeys(o[k], keys))
    || keys
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `keys` to a parameter you pass recursively:

```js
const getAllKeys = (object, keys = []) => {
  Object.keys(object).some((k) => {
    if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === "object") {
      keys.push(k);
      getAllKeys(object[k], keys);
    }
  });
  return keys;
};

const obj = {
  key1: {
    key2: {
      key3: {}
    }
  }
};

const result = getAllKeys(obj);

console.log(result);
```

This does mean that the first call might be `getAllKeys(obj, ["some" "keys", "already", "present"])` or even something invalid like `getAllKeys(obj, null)`. If you want to make sure that doesn't happen, convert your function to a recursion helper function and you can have a top level function that makes sure to call it correctly:

```js
const getAllKeys = (object) => {
  const helper = (object, keys) => {
//      ^^^^^^ now an internal helper
    Object.keys(object).some((k) => {
      if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === "object") {
        keys.push(k);
        helper(object[k], keys);
//      ^^^^^^ recursively calls itself
      }
    });
    return keys;
  }
  
  //top level function just calls the helper:
  return helper(object, []);
};

const obj = {
  key1: {
    key2: {
      key3: {}
    }
  }
};

const result = getAllKeys(obj);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter` and `flatMap` to get a *functional programming* solution:

```js
const getAllKeys = object => 
    Object.keys(object)
          .concat(Object.values(object)
                        .filter(obj => Object(obj) === obj)
                        .flatMap(getAllKeys));

const obj = {
  key1: {
    key2: {
      key3: {}
    }
  }
};

console.log(getAllKeys(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```js
const getAllKeys=(o,keys=[])=>{
  const gak=object=>{
    Object.keys(object).some((k) => {
      if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === "object") {
        keys.push(k);
        gak(object[k]);
      }
    });
  };
  gak(o);
  return keys;
}

const obj = {
  key1: {
    key2: {
      key3: {}
    }
  }
};

console.log(getAllKeys(obj));
```

Having `keys` as an optional argument allows you to re-use it in case you want to collect keys over several objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your function always return an array of **keys**. You can get result of recursive function inside this function and push it with destructuring syntax:

```
let nestedKeys = getAllKeys(object[k]);
keys.push(...nestedKeys);
```

All function could be like this:

```
const getAllKeys = (object) => {
    let keys = [];

    Object.keys(object).some((k) => {
        if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === "object") {
            keys.push(k);
            let nestedKeys = getAllKeys(object[k]);
            keys.push(...nestedKeys);
        }
    });
    return keys;
};
```

Also be careful, because code like this `typeof object[k] === "object"` returns `true` for `Array` and `null`